# What is a function's function signature if it uses a custom type? (Stuct, enum, etc)

Tags: function-selector, enum

I have the following Enum that is an input to a function

```js
enum Cat {
    Tabby,
    Rascal,
    Cool
}

function hiMom(Cat myCat) public {
```

What is the function signature of `hiMom(Cat)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to know the functions parameters [elementary type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html?highlight=selector#types) and use that.

For an enum, the type is `uint8`.

You can determine this using the `--abi` option to `solc` (or other compilers):

```bash
❯ solc --abi - <<EOF | tail -1 | jq 
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

enum Cat {
    Tabby,
    Rascal,
    Cool
}

contract Foo {
  function hiMom(Cat myCat) public {}
}
EOF
[
  {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "enum Cat",
        "name": "myCat",
        "type": "uint8"
               # ^^^^^ <- THIS IS THE BASE TYPE <------------
      }
    ],
    "name": "hiMom",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  }
]
```

In [cast](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-sig?highlight=cast%20sig#cast-sig):

```
cast sig "hiMom(uint8)"
```

### Tuple/Struct Edit

Note, for a tuple or struct type, you'll need to combine the components into parentheses.

Example:

```js
struct animal {
  string breed;
  uint256 id;
}

function getName(animal myAnimal) public {
```

`getName` would have a function selector of: `0x5e492cc7`

You could find it by:

```
cast sig "getName((string,uint256))"
```

Comment: Shouldnt the first line of this answer refer to the input's elementary type and not the "function's" elementary type?

Comment: Yes - I've updated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to know the functions [elementary type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html?highlight=selector#types) and use that.

For an enum, the type is `uint8`. You can often find this information from the  compiler information in the ABI.

In [cast](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-sig?highlight=cast%20sig#cast-sig):

```
cast sig "hiMom(uint8)"
```

Comment: For an enum, the type is uint8, and also returns uint8 if its return type is enum.